# Express Proxy Server, to Proxy Fiddler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fiddler, proxy-server

I have a node.js express proxy server, which I would like to debug, So I want to capture the traffic through fiddler:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express();
const proxyTarget = 'https://my-proxy.azurewebsites.net/proxy';

//attempting to configure fiddler proxy 
process.env.https_proxy= 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
process.env.http_proxy= 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0;

expressApp.use('/api', proxy({
    target: proxyTarget,
    secure: false, // don't verify https certificates
    logLevel: 'debug'
}));
```

I've tried to capture traffic using fiddler but fiddler doesn't capture the request to Azure, only the wrapped proxy request on localhost.

How can I configure my proxy settings so that first I pass through fiddler?

Comment: If you only see the CONNECT requests in fiddler this usually means that the Fiddler root CA certificate is not trusted by the application.

Comment: I don't see any, the node proxy for some reason still doesn't respect the proxy settings for fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Node.js doesn't listen to the http_proxy/https_proxy environment variables (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8381 for the full debate).

That means this is difficult with Fiddler - you need to change every place where HTTP requests are made to use the proxy settings, or to replace Node's [default agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent) to do so (and then ensure no requests set a custom agent). There are some node modules that can help here, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-agent, but you'll also need to handle HTTPS trust separately (or you'll just see unreadable CONNECT requests, as mentioned by the commenter above).

I have hit this same issue myself though, so I've been building an open-source alternative to Fiddler to fix it! [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/javascript) can do what you're looking for: you can open a terminal from there (or enable it in an existing terminal) and any node processes started there will automatically have all HTTP & HTTPS requests intercepted, so you can examine and/or rewrite them, just like Fiddler. It handles all the cert trust stuff too.

Under the hood, this is just wrapping `node` on the command line to do the same thing you'd do manually to do that, reconfiguring settings & defaults to ensure everything plays nicely. If you do want to do that manually, the full source to do so is here: https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-server/blob/master/overrides/js/prepend-node.js

Comment: Hello, I have a closed-source node.js app that opens links in the browser when certain conditions are met. I also have a node.js script written by myself which I'd like to execute taking as input the URL opened by the aforementioned app. Is it possible to listen to the HTTPS request made by the closed-source app, save the URL in a variable and then pass that as an argument to my script so that I can work on it?

Comment: @cholmugod it depends. The node app there isn't sending a request, instead it's probably launching a subprocess or using an OS API to request that the system opens a browser in its preferred URL. To capture that, you'll need to intercept that, which isn't HTTP at all. Maybe you could register your script as the system browser, so it launches when pages are opened? Or you could hook the `open` (on Mac) or `xdg-open` (on Linux) commands in that environment? It's going to be messy.

Comment: How can my Node.js script be the system browser? I don't get it.